# Android WebView JavaScript callback to original View

Tags: android, webview, callback

I am writing an android app in which i insert javascript code in a webview and then the javascript replies by calling a java method specified with `webview.addJavascriptInterface`.

The problem is that the javascript-callback is running in another thread than the original view from which i started the process. Because of that i cant access the original view.

How can i access the original view?

I am using api level 7.

Here are the important code fragments:

JavaScript call:

```
webview.addJavascriptInterface(this, "ACall");
webview.loadUrl("javascript: ACall.update();");
```

Callback:

```
public void update() {
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    Log.v("test", "test");
    tv.setText("test");
}
```

And the stacktrace:

```
Uncaught handler: thread WebViewCoreThread exiting due to uncaught exception
ndroid.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2706)
at android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:560)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:5380)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2684)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2552)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2527)
at shylux.android.GameActivity.update(GameActivity.java:53)
at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(Native Method)
at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(Native Method)
at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.loadUrl(BrowserFrame.java:149)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore.loadUrl(WebViewCore.java:1449)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$1400(WebViewCore.java:48)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:890)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:611)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

//////////////// Current solution:

This is my current solution. I think there have to be a better way. This requires a lot of work if you want to do different tasks.

```
public void update() {
    tv.post(new UpdateTask());
}

private class UpdateTask implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        tv.setText("test");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Thanks, I had a similar problem.
The solution with `runOnUiThread` was surprisingly simple.

You can not update the UI of the activity from outside the thread in which it was originally created. `runOnUiThread()` method is used for doing UI changes.

```
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.practice_ri_wrong_3);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

[runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) is your friend. Just cook up a Runnable that makes the changes you need to your view, and pass it to runOnUiThread. The [painless threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) article suggests some other options you might consider (if you don't have a handle on the activity, then tv.post might be a goer).

Comment: ok i got it running. but as i already wrote, i hope there is a better solution. maybe there is already such a class? i will read the painless threading article properly. hope i can find something useful.